# How to access the DOM element of some external library in a parent component where it is used in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I need to manipulate the styling and visibility of a button that is present in one of the external library component. For better understanding below is the scenario.

parent.component.html
`<child-component></child-component>`

child.component.html
`<external-component></external-component>`

So the button is present in an external library component which I need to manipulate in the parent component.

Note: The button does not have any template reference variable and since it is present in external library I can not add it in its html.

Is there any way this can be done?
Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the component file add the following code

```
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-my-contract',
   templateUrl: './my.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./my-contract.component.css']
})
export class MbpContractComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('myInput') myInputVariable: ElementRef
```

}

In your code you can use like

```
this.myInputVariable.nativeElement.disabled = true;
```

Or you can use any properties on that element

Comment: I mentioned in my question that the button does not have any variable name attached to it and i can not add it since it is in external library component

Comment: Try accessing parent element and then access the child